# jquery is erasing my html selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following, i'm trying to change the options displayed by a select based on the choices a user makes, in it's most basic from, the code for doing something like that would look as follows:

**HTML**

```
<select id="ddlExpedientes" class="drop-down">
    <option value="imagen1.txt">1</option>
    <option value="imagen2.txt">2</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlExpedientesPension" class="drop-down">
    <option value="imagen1.txt">1</option>
    <option value="imagen2.txt">2</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlExpedientesHistoria" class="drop-down">
    <option value="imagenb1.txt">b1</option>
    <option value="imagenb2.txt">b2</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlExpedientesSalario" class="drop-down">
    <option value="imagenc1.txt">c1</option>
    <option value="imagenc2.txt">c2</option>
</select>

<a id="pension">pension</a>
<a id="historia">pension</a>
<a id="salario">pension</a>
```

**JS**

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var that  = $(this);
    var drop = $('#ddlExpedientes');

    if(that.attr("id") =="pension")
    {
        var options = $("#ddlExpedientesPension option");
        drop.empty().append(options);

        //drop.append(options);

    }

    if(that.attr("id") =="historia")
    {
        var options = $("#ddlExpedientesHistoria option");
        drop.empty().append(options);

        //drop.append(options);
    }

    if(that.attr("id") =="salario")
    {
        var options = $("#ddlExpedientesSalario option");
        drop.empty().append(options);

        //drop.append(options);
    }
});
```

As you can see, i have 3 selects, each one representing a "source" of the information, but, no matter what i do, the "source" for the selectections i want to display gets deleted after each "insert" to the main select, making it impossible to selecte a source more than once.

I just don't know what to do, or why this is happening; and to make things worst, i have a really similar piece code on my application and i never had that problem, at all. so my questions are, ¿what is wrong with this code?, ¿why is it doing what it's doing? and ¿who to fix it? .

**Example FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/r86KE/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `clone()` the `option` elements before you append them so you are appending a copy, not the original element:

```
drop.empty().append(options.clone(true));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r86KE/5/)

Note that you can also DRY that code up by refactoring the repeated functionality into functions and passing the changing parts as parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeahy, was reading a little more on the documentation about .append(), and as it turns out, it "Moves" the elements if there is only 1 target, for some reason, its not doing so on my other code when im doing pretty much exactly the same, as for DRYing the code, it was just a "test" code, to try and narrow down the problem, no excuse for being lazy, but just saying the code was not the final product ;), Thanks a lot for your help :D.

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch the html.

like this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var that  = $(this);
    var drop = $('#ddlExpedientes');

    if(that.attr("id") =="pension")
    {
        var options = $("#ddlExpedientesPension").html();
        drop.empty().append(options);

        //drop.append(options);

    }

    if(that.attr("id") =="historia")
    {
        var options = $("#ddlExpedientesHistoria").html();
        drop.empty().append(options);

        //drop.append(options);
    }

    if(that.attr("id") =="salario")
    {
        var options = $("#ddlExpedientesSalario").html();
        drop.empty().append(options);

        //drop.append(options);
    }
})
```

Comment: Never thought of using the HTML() like this, thanks, still, i found Rory's solution to be more elegant.